# How to determine which column NA was added to by coercion

Tags: r, coercion

I'm trying to identify which columns NA was added to by coercion. Particularly if I have a very large data table. Using a smaller table as an example to convert the table from character to numeric (read from excel sheet).

clean_tab data:

```
A tibble: 3 x 3
          a b                   c    
      <dbl> <chr>               <chr>
    1   0.5 4-2                 5    
    2   0.1 0.29999999999999999 3-1  
    3   0.3 0.40000000000000002 4
```

Code applied to data:

```
b <- c(1,2,3)
clean_tab[, b] <- sapply(clean_tab[, b], as.numeric)
View(clean_tab)
```

Resulting warning messages and output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
> clean_tab
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.5  NA       5
2   0.1   0.3    NA
3   0.3   0.4     4
```

In this case as it is a smaller table, I can clearly see where the NA's were added. How would I identify which columns (and even more specifically row and column) in which an NA was added if the table was much larger?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind` as TRUE to return the row/column index of the `NA` elements

```
which(is.na(clean_tab), arr.ind = TRUE)
#   row col
#1   1   2
#2   2   3
```

---

as the input data is a `tibble`, we can make use of `tidyverse` methods for conversion

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
clean_tab %<>%
         mutate_at(b, as.numeric)
```

#### data

```
clean_tab <- structure(list(a = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3), b = c("4-2", 
    "0.29999999999999999", "0.40000000000000002"), 
c = c("5", "3-1", "4")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, this will definitely tell the locations of the NA's present. But how to differentiate between NA's that were initially in the data frame and NA's generated by applying as.numeric is still what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Tillie  If that is the case, you can make the NA's to some other value before the transformation and then change it later ie. `clean_tab[is.na(clean_tab)] <- "-999"`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would could take would be to attempt to convert each column to numeric, then assert whether any `NA` values resulted from that attempt:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3),
                 b=c("4-2", "0.29999999999999999", "0.40000000000000002"),
                 c=c("5", "3-1", "4"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

names(df)[sapply(df, function(x) { sum(is.na(as.numeric(x))) > 0 })]

[1] "b" "c"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, this was along the lines of what I was looking for but it would also return columns that initially had NA in it (if NA was added to column a instead of 0.3 when you ran the code the output would be [1] "a" "b" "c")